# java - select multiple values

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar

I need help. In my code I implemented a scroll bar but how can i select more than one value. for example how can i select like apple and orange at the same time. I cant see how to do it. Can someone please let me see how it is done. Thank you.

here is the code:

```
package lab;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.collections.*;
    import javafx.event.*;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.layout.*;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.shape.*;
    import javafx.scene.paint.*;

    public class pizza extends Application{
        private ComboBox<String> size;
        private ListView<String> toppings;
        private TextField order;
        private Button orderit, clearit;
        private Label lb_flavor, lb_tops, lb_order;
        private ObservableList<String> flavor =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList (
                        "Small", "Medium",
                        "Large", "extra Large");
        private ObservableList<String> tps =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        "pineapples", "pepperoni",
                        "peppers", "bacon", "sausage",
                        "ham");
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            // areas to place the various components
            VBox pane = new VBox(15);
            HBox flavor_pane = new HBox(10);
            HBox topping_pane = new HBox(10);
            HBox order_pane = new HBox(10);

            lb_flavor = new Label("Sizes");
            size = new ComboBox(flavor);
            size.setVisibleRowCount(4);
            size.setValue(flavor.get(0)); // display the first one

            flavor_pane.getChildren().addAll(lb_flavor, size);

            lb_tops = new Label("toppings");
            toppings = new ListView(tps);
            toppings.setPrefSize(100,80);
    toppings.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);


            topping_pane.getChildren().addAll(lb_tops, toppings);

            lb_order = new Label("Order Summary");
            order = new TextField();
            order.setEditable(false);
            order.setPrefColumnCount(25);

            order_pane.getChildren().addAll(lb_order, order);

            orderit = new Button("Place Order");
            clearit = new Button("Clear Order");

            // Subscribe for when the user clicks the buttons
            OrderHandler oh = new OrderHandler();
            orderit.setOnAction(oh);
            clearit.setOnAction(oh);

            pane.getChildren().addAll(flavor_pane,
                    topping_pane, order_pane, orderit, clearit);

            Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 300);
            primaryStage.setTitle("pizza ordering");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Application.launch(args);
        }
    class OrderHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            // was it the clear button  
            if (e.getSource() == clearit) {
                order.setText("");
                toppings.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                size.setValue(flavor.get(0));
                return;
            }
            // flavor
            String result = size.getValue();
            // for toppings
            ObservableList<String> selections =
            toppings.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            // convert to an array
            Object[] objs = selections.toArray();
            for (int k =0 ; k < objs.length; k++){
                result += " " + objs[k].toString();
            }
            order.setText(result);
        }
    }
    }
```

It is a pizza ordering system. when it runs u have to select the size from a scroll bar and then the toppings from a scroll bar. then once order is pressed. what is ordered will appear in order summary. Now all I need is to select 2 toppings at once but you can only select one as of now. Thank you

Comment: That works just as I expect; if you select multiple toppings and press "place order" they all get listed out in the text field. Can you explain what behavior you want that is different to what it is doing?

Comment: well I am only capable of selecting one value but not multiple values

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure you are running the version you have posted?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with how it runs but like selecting ham and bacon at the same time.

Comment: or maybe should it be a check box

Comment: A series of check boxes might be easier, sure, but again, it seems to work fine. Click on ham, control-click (or cmd-click on mac, or whatever you normally use to multiple select on whatever platform you're running on) on bacon, press "place order", both appear in the output. What output are you seeing when you do that?

Comment: when i click on bacon and then try to click on ham bacon deselects

Comment: I see it now but i would rather not have to press ctrl if I would like to select both.

Comment: That's pretty much the standard way for multiple selection in a list-type control. I'd suggest you use check boxes if you don't want the user to press control.

Comment: how would I make it into a check box. I have never used a check box. So can someone show me how I can make it one.

Comment: You can also use a event filter for the the mouse pressed event on the `ListCell`s to consume the event and update the selection yourself by adding/removing the index of the item corresponding to the cell to/from the selection. That way you prevent the `ListView` receiving those events and removing all other items from the selection.